# WPF window has different colors in VS designer than when debugging?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

The WPF window background color is white during design in Visual Studio, but when I debug the application, it is black instead. Why?

Here is my .xaml code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="XLTT.Views.About"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

         ShowTitleBar="False"
         WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
         ShowCloseButton="False"
         ResizeMode="NoResize" 
         WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
         Height="320" 
         Width="400" 
         Title="About" >


<!-- your content here -->
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="lblAppName" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Application Name :" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Foreground="#FFF53800"/>
    <TextBlock Name="lblBuild" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Build :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
    <TextBlock Name="lblOwner" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Owner :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="16" />
    <TextBlock Name="lblLicense" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="License" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="3" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEA1818" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="16" />
    <Button Name="btnOk" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="94" Grid.Row="4" Click="btnOk_Click" Height="40"/>

</Grid>
```

[image: Colors in designer]
[image: Colors when running]

Comment: Please Read my Update, and try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `App.xaml` File.

If it contains:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
```

Replace it with:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

---

**Explanation**

Your `App.xaml` is the entry point for your program an will apply the style settings to every child Window / Page / Control, but often the VS Designer can't load all resources in designing mode. So in VS it will be default white and on running the Application applies the styles completely.

MahApps use 2 default [style templates](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#app) for windows:

> "BaseLight", "BaseDark"

---

**Testing**

Of course if it's not in the `App.xaml` you can check this with `ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(this);` in your MetroWindow Constructor debugging.

Or override in your `App.xaml.cs` the `OnStartup()` Methode like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup (StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the theme from the current application
        var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);

        // now set the Green accent and dark theme
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                                    ThemeManager.GetAccent("Blue"),
                                    ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseLight"));

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

After your telling us that there is no `App.xaml` Entry Point in your Application the problem is clear. MahApps requires some resource dictionaries, as you can read at the [Quick Start Guide](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html).

I think in your case **you just missing the styles** for MahApps. So add, after your `<Controls:MetroWindow>` Tag following:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

Comment: Cool. I don't have any file called App.xml however. And when I search the solution for BaseDark.xaml, VS doesn't find any match.

Comment: What is MetroWindow Constructor debugging? A google search doesn't show any good results.

Comment: The file call `App.xaml` with an `a`. This is not an XML File.

Comment: And you will definitely have this file. It's major important ;)

Comment: I don't think that I have. I can't find it in the project explorer. Maybe its because I don't have a WPF project in VS. I have only added a WPF item to an existing C# project.

Comment: @user1283776 This is some **IMPORTANT** Information!

Comment: That's what StackOverflow is for ;)